# feature calculated : Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe mydataset_df :

```
COMPANY_CODE    LEASE_ID    LEASE_START2
0   000340  22323   2019-07-15
1   000625  20948   2019-04-15
2   000652  20219   2019-06-15
3   000722  20455   2019-07-15
4   001019  20129   2019-06-15
```

I create a new dataframe with calculated feature:

```
customer = mydataset_df.groupby('COMPANY_CODE').LEASE_START2.max().reset_index()
customer.columns = ['COMPANY_CODE', 'MAX_LEASE_START']
```

I try now to add a feature to customer dataframe :

```
customer['FREQUENCY']= mydataset_df.groupby('COMPANY_CODE').LEASE_ID.count().reset_index()
```

but i got this error :

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1
```

Any idea please to fix this problem? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because the `reset_index()` method is unable to determine the correct placement for the index values.

To resolve this issue, you can try specifying the `drop=True` parameter in the `reset_index()` method.

```
customer = ydataset_df.groupby('COMPANY_CODE').LEASE_START2.max().reset_index(drop=True)
```